# How to prevent a div from disappearing when you hover a link in pure css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, submenu

first of all sorry for my english I'm going to try to be as precise as possible, here is my problem:

In my css I created a div displayed with none, and when I hover on a link in the nav I changed the display with display block it is a simple sub-nav pattern. But here is my problem, once i'm hovering my link when I leave it my sub menu disappears automatically, so how do I keep my sub menu in display block even if i'm not hovering the trigger anymore and all of that in pure css (it is an exercice for me):

here is my repo on github : https://github.com/MehdiAlouafi/Int-gration-Briefing-2

Comment: Can you make a fiddle  it would be easier to help

Comment: here it is :) https://jsfiddle.net/hv2a18y7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a couple of mistakes.

```
/* First of all it's better to have your list-item relative. */
nav ul > li {
  position:relative;
}

/* Then your .on-hover can have simpler top and left coordinates. */ 
.on-hover {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(243,243,241);
  width: 165px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(96, 96, 96, 0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}

/* You want the hovering to be over the entire li.*/
nav ul > li:hover .on-hover {
  display: block;
}
```

You had the hover work like this. Which means it stops hovering when you leave the #test being the anchor(`<a>`) element

```
#test:hover + .on-hover {
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3su9jppc/1/

Comment: Man... thanks a lot... I love you !
I just begin coding like 2month ago so this is new for me but thanks to you i learning a few thing today! 
Thank you so much Yeouu !! :)